# Sudo installation problems

Tags: debian, software-installation, sudo

I just downloaded Debian 9.6.0 from osboxes to run it on a VM.
However, I ran into a few problems.
I can't sudo. Ok, you have to install it first. No problems... I thought. Turns out, there are a few indeed for me.
After looking up google I found:

```
apt-get install sudo -y
```

which ends up in `Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resoruce temporarily unavailable` as well as `Unable to lock the admin directory /var/lib/dpkg/, is another process using it?`.
Bear in mind I was logged in as the default osboxes.org account and used `su` before.

The answer from GDA3R resolved the lock issue. However when I try to `apt-get install sudo` I get `please insert the disc labeled Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_` which can be resolved by commenting out the line in services.list. However, this file is read only and I cant edit it.

the sources.list is as follows

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25]/ stretch contrib main

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25]/ stretch contrib main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
```

I think I should outcomment the second deb cdrom.
I can open the file in the terminal. However, trying to insert a # results in cursor jumping to first deb and returning `?\<deb\>` in last line

Comment: Do you have another package manager operation in progress? Check backgrounded jobs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for the auto-update to be accomplished through the `apt-daily.service` service ( in background ).

Or you can stop the `apt-daily.service` and the running `apt` instance , then run the aborted task manually (as root):

```
systemctl stop apt-daily.service
pkill apt
dpkg-configure -a
apt update
apt install sudo
```

To solve the error:

```
please insert the disc labeled Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_...
```

As root , comment or remove the cdrom repository from your `sources.list`.

This is an example of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file from [Debian Wiki :Sources- List](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
```

> If you also want the contrib and non-free components, add `contrib non-free` after `main`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello you need to remove the cdrom entry from the sources.list file.
To fix this just go to the command line and type:

```
sudo sed -i '/cdrom/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And this will fix it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, however, that the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493205/377345) alread mentions removing the CDOM entry from the `sources.list`. If you want to highlight this aspect more prominently or add a concrete example on how to do it, you may want to submit an edit suggestion to that answer.